# '+' causing bad request in URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am Server.UrlEncode on some query string parameters and locally it is fine but on my server (IIS 7) it causing a Bad Request error.  I am using ASP.Net MVC.

If I manually change the + to a dash - the request works fine.

This breaks:

```
 http://www.example.com/Glenn+Pang/234
```

This works:

```
http://www.example.com/Glenn-Pang/234
```

Is this a setting I am missing in IIS 7?

Comment: Since you are asking specifically about IIS 7 rather than about `UrlEncode` or something of that nature, you might want to try ServerFault... More IIS guys on there...

Comment: I disagree, this is more a question about ASP.Net MVC. He just gave context that he is running it on IIS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + symbol is also the symbol for a space when URL Encoded. Could it be your routes are set up expecting the plus, which never arrives because actually its a space? I'm not sure why this would work on your local machine, but not on the IIS box though.

Edit: An [un-validated random page on the net](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) suggests that certain symbols must be encoded unless being used for their specific purpose. I'm not sure this applies to the + as my thought is that it's special purpose is representing spaces in URLs - but I guess %20 is worth a shot if that helps in any way? (And I appreciate, + rocks for Friendly URLs way more than %20 does)

Comment: Yeah I knew the + was for white space, route is setup to expect a string so I would assume this would be o.k.

Comment: If you're expecting a space according to your route, then it's not this. Have you tried replacing the + with a %20, what result does that give?

Comment: GAH - I want nice URL's so I guess I have to craft them myself.  For some reason I assumed URLEncode would create valid URL's - how silly of me

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129 - this is a registry setting that can be chnaged (AllowRestrictedChars) - not sure if I want to do this or not.

Comment: Sucks. I think there is something missing with regards to the +. I don't suppose the error logs on IIS provided anything useful? Sometimes they can elude to other issues, but it'll probably be the fact that the + is in part of the "file" in the URL, rather than the QueryString? (speculation comment)